# How to reason or make inferences using hermit reasoner in command line

Tags: semantic-web, owl, owl-api

I am totally new to the idea of Semantic web and Reasoner so sorry for being naive.

I downloaded the HermiT.zip package from http://www.hermit-reasoner.com

Then I added a Demo.Java file to the project and ran this in the command prompt using the commands given on the the same website.

The ontology on which I used the reasoner was pizza.owl which i got from this website - http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~michael/sw/slides/pizza.owl

The only result it shows is "TRUE" but I want to reason things in a ontology.
For example :

Transitivity of rdfs:subClassOf and rdfs:subPropertyOf.

(rdfs:subClassOf Dog Mammal)

(rdfs:subClassOf Mammal Animal)

imply the fact

(rdfs:subClassOf Dog Animal)

How can i make these queries ? Do I need to write some java code to do so ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think HermiT offers a command line interface, but you can try this example from Owl api which allows simple queries on the command line

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/DL-Queries-with-a-real-reasoner

Comment: If not command line interface then where can these queries be made ? I have used Protege, but i didn't use any queries there. I simply made an ontology and when I ran the reasoner then the reasoner inferred the missing things.

Comment: Also, if I have to make any inference as given in the example of my question, do I need to write java codes to query them and then run the project in the command prompt to get the results ?

Comment: You're after the inferred hierarchy - you can get it from HermiT with Java code, see the examples on the same wiki linked above.

Comment: I have never used java before and am finding all that syntax really hard to get, specially because all that syntax is specifically associated to reasoners (I think so, but I am not sure what I said is right and it might just be plain java syntax as I am unaware of java syntax too). Is there any document that can help me understand how to write java codes so as to use hermit reasoner to derive those inferred hierarchy ?

Comment: The Java code required to call a reasoner is not particularly complex Java, so I would think your main difficulty comes from the language rather than this particular application. I would suggest getting some familiarity with Java on a simpler topic - having to learn both Java and Semantic Web at the same time is hard.

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar HermiT.jar -c -ooutput.owl pizza.owl
```

The output.owl file will contain the results. Additional details on the command line interface for HermiT can be found at http://www.hermit-reasoner.com/command.html.

Comment: java -jar HermiT.jar -ooutput.owl file:///Users/kcason/Desktop/apis/HermiT/pizza.owl https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hermit-users/caEwsCve320